# Where's the leak in this code so I can call the plumber?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

Ok, caught you by the title.  But in all seriousness, I can't figure out where the leak is coming from in my code.  Running it in instruments doesn't show leaks, but it's warning me when I analyze it.  Here's the suspect code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"Table";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    if (cityCount >= 1) {

        NSString *city = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@,  %@", 
                          [[cityData objectAtIndex:row] objectAtIndex:0], 
                          [[cityData objectAtIndex:row] objectAtIndex:1], 
                          [[cityData objectAtIndex:row] objectAtIndex:2]
                          //,[[cityData objectAtIndex:row] objectAtIndex:3]
                          ];

        cell.textLabel.text = city;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]; 
        return cell;
    }

    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"No cities were found";
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]; 
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell; //Here's the warning
                     //Potential leak of an object allocated on line 64 and stored into 'cell'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call `autorelease`.  Change this:

```
 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
```

To this:

```
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Comment: I got same issue with ARC. Still I need to autorelease it. please help.

Answer (score 5):

When you allocate the `cell`, you should `autorelease` it. When you allocate something, you're the owner, and you must release it. Since you return the cell, the only option you have is to autorelease it.

Take a look at the memory management rules [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

The code should be like this:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier]
  autorelease];
```

*No need for a plumber now...*

Comment: Thanks, that just slipped by me to autorelease. :)